# Air core inductor impedance vs frequency graphs

Tags: inductor, impedance, inductance, high-frequency, phase

I wanted an inductor with at least 100 μH, so I used a PVC pipe and some enamelled wire (AWG 21 if I recall correctly) to create an inductor. The inductor does serve its purpose fine as a load inductor, but running a sweep on the KeySight E4900A impedance analyzer gives this peculiar Z-theta graph:

[image]

The impedance seems to start to drop before a phase change occurs, so while still being in the inductive region. I remember I've seen this type of behavior before, and it was again with an air core inductor with spacing between the turns (this one has no spacing, and a bit above 50 turns).

I was wondering if someone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the resonant or waveguide modes of the helical structure.

I won't pretend to know the finer details of analysis, but do enjoy this surprisingly extensive reference: 
https://hamwaves.com/inductance/en/index.html#frequently-asked-questions 
Includes a calculator at the top, incorporating all the approximations and empirical data discussed below.  It's the most accurate solenoid calculator on the internet I'm aware of.

In short, the critical frequency is basically the λ/4 point of the total wire length; but wound up in a helix, the impedance and velocity are different, and especially the velocity is dependent on frequency, i.e. it is dispersive.  Whereas on a straight wire (read: ideal coax or such), these modes would be strictly harmonic, but here, they are distorted, spaced a bit closer than that.  So it's not quite the λ/4 point, it's a bit off, and so too, all the higher modes.  If you continue to probe higher frequencies, you will see they alternate approximately above and below a center (characteristic) impedance, but that center line wanders as it goes.  Whereas the peaks and valleys are equidistant (on a log scale) from \$Z_0\$ for the case of a coax stub.

The modes arise in much the same way as any other waveguide problem, given that the velocity and impedance vary as mentioned; you get asymptotic behavior below cutoff (which is to say, TEM00 mode).  In other words, it's an inductor-as-you-know-it below these resonant frequencies, of which the lowest is the λ/4 mode, and things get messy above there so you really just prefer to avoid driving it at those frequencies.

Other structures have, predictably, other characteristic frequencies.  For example, if we take the helix, bend it around into a loop (as in a single-layer toroidial winding), and look at the resonant frequencies, we find that 1λ is the first resonant mode: the continuity condition of the first and last turns being adjacent means the lower (fractional) modes are prohibited.  This mode is equivalent to that of a ringing bell, or singing wine glass.  And indeed, these modes have real consequences in circuits: some current transformers are constructed this way, and have much worse transient response than you would hope for!

If you're not so keen on wave mechanics as yet, a hand-waving TLDR:

Suffice it to say, we can approximate the turn-to-turn capacitance that's distributed through the coil, add it up, and find the falling slope after the first (parallel resonant) peak.  And we don't need to stop there, we can subdivide the coil into two coils stacked up, each with their own (now lesser) capacitance, and some coupling of their inductance.  Thus the two coils are series resonant together.  Or into thirds, where two act in series and one more acts as a parallel resonant on top of them.  And so on and so forth, the modes always alternating, peak and valley, as we divide it into smaller and smaller chunks.

In this way, we can approximate the component as an RLC network, of which only the first order is represented with the (R + L) || C network shown in the figure.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the self resonant frequency (SRF) of the inductor. The SRF depends on the self-capacitance of the winding and the inductance.

In your case, the inductance is 193 μH and winding capacitance is 4.8 pF as indicated in the equivalent circuit parameters shown in the lower left of the display. This says that one might expect the SRF to be around 5.2 MHz.

Another way of looking at the issue:
Looking at the impedance graph, at 10 kHz, the |Z| is about 16 ohms which gives an inductance of \$ {X_L \over{2\pi f}} \approx 255 uH \$. This [web site](https://www.teslascientific.com/products/coil-capacitance-calculator/) has a self capacitance estimator for a single layer air core inductor based on the work by R.G. Medhurst. Assuming the length of the inductor = 1.5" and the diameter is 0.84" (1/2" schedule 40 PVC pipe), the self capacitance is approximately 1 pF (doesn't take in to consideration the dielectric constant of the PVC which will increase the capacitance slightly). This puts the SRF at about 10 MHz.

Comment: @Grigoris & qrk: Here is Medhurst's 1947 article - 24 pages of useful magic.
|| ["H. F. Resistance and Self-Capacitance of Single-Layer Solenoids"](https://hamwaves.com/inductance/doc/medhurst.1947.pdf) , R G Medhurst (GEC Research Labs.). Wireless Engineer, Feb 1947 p35-43, Mar 1947 p80-92.